# In Extjs how can we remove decimal values from 3D Bar Y-axis?

Tags: extjs

[image]

I'm using type: 'bar3d', Extjs 6.0.2.
Inside items i've

```
 axes: [{
          type: 'numeric3d',
          integerOnly: true,
          minimum: 0,
          minorTickSteps: 1,
         },
       {
         type: 'category3d',
         grid: true,                        
         title: {
              text: 'Queues'
            }
      }]
```

How can i remove the decimals from y-axis? I'm pushing only integer values to the y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to set *majorTickSteps* on the axis to match the difference between the *maximum* and *minimum* values of the axis.  As you have set the minimum to 0, you just need to determine the maximum value of the *calls* field in the store.  This will automatically become the *maximum* value on the axis so *maximum* does not need to be set.

```
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric3d',
            minimum: 0,
            majorTickSteps: store.max('calls'),
            fields: ['calls']
        }, {
            type: 'category3d',
            position: 'bottom',
            title: 'Categories',
            fields: ['name'],
        }],
```

See fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1iqp

If you had non-integer values, you would need to set the *maximum* and the *majorTickSteps* to the next highest integer greater than the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Decimals in the Y axis can be easily removed by adding a small checking on the axes rendering.

```
axes: [{
        type: 'numeric3d',
        position: 'left',
        minimum:0,                      
        fields: ['field1','field2'], 
        renderer: function (label, layout, lastLabel) {
            var string = layout.toString(); 
            var found = string.indexOf('.');
            if(found == '-1') {
                return layout;  
            } else {
                return ' '
            }

        },
        grid: {
            odd: {
                fillStyle: 'rgba(245, 245, 245, 2)'
            },
            even: {
                fillStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 2)'
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Title Name'
        }

    }]
```